# Python: procura e comparação de valores em Dicionários

Tags: python, pandas, comparação, planilha

O meu projeto envolve duas fontes de dados. 
Pra ser simples, vamos dizer duas planilhas. Ambas com cinco linhas, com Id e valor.
No cenário real, seria uma planilha .xlsx e uma consulta SQL.

```
id valor          id valor
5   10            1   20
1   20            2   50
2   50            5   0
4   100           3   150
3   150           4   100
```

Leio elas com "`read_excel`" e transformo as planilhas em dicionário com o "`to_dict`" da biblioteca "**pandas**".

No cenário real, as planilhas não serão do mesmo tamanho, estariam tudo misturadas.

Então dentro de um loop, como posso fazer com que o python procure o id da planilha1 dentro da planilha2 e compare o valor das duas planilhas?
Ele identificaria se o id "5" está na planilha2, e se sim, compararia o valor da planilha1 e planilha2.
Se for igual, "printa" a linha comparada da planilha1.

Tenho ideias como vai ser o meu output final, tipo uma nova coluna booleana na 1ª planilha, mas eu só estou empacado na comparação mesmo.
Se tiver outra maneira de fazer isso, me avise.

```py
import pandas as pds

file = ('planilha 1.xlsx')
df = pds.read_excel(file)
file2 = ('planilha 2.xlsx')
df2 = pds.read_excel(file2)

planilha1 = df.to_dict(orient='records')
planilha2 = df2.to_dict(orient='records')
```

Comment: Você pode fazer um [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) pelo `id` e terá como resultado um dataframe com as duas colunas `valor` dos dataframes originais, com valores já alinhados onde o `id` for igual. Aí você pode fazer as comparações que quiser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não ficou claro na pergunta mas pelo escopo que você trouxe não há motivos ou necessidade de transformar os DataFrames carregados em dicionários, é possível resolver tudo isso diretamente com o Pandas :)

Para que tu consiga verificar as linhas que possuem a **id e valor** iguais sem perder informação eu usaria o `.merge` por **id** para unir as tabelas e criaria uma coluna booleana que assinala onde o **valor** é igual entre elas, desta forma:

```
#Carregar os dados
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id' : [5,1,2,4,3],
               'valor': [10,20,50,100,150]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id' : [1,2,5,3,4],
               'valor': [20,50,0,150,100]})

#Fazer a união entre os DaTaFrames
new_df = df1.merge(df2, on=['id'])
#Criar a coluna booleana que marca as linhas iguais
new_df = new_df.assign(is_equal = new_df['valor_x'].eq(new_df['valor_y']))
new_df.head()
#saida:

    id  valor_x valor_y is_equal
0   5   10      0       False
1   1   20      20      True
2   2   50      50      True
3   4   100     100     True
4   3   150     150     True
```

Agora se o que você busca é apenas as ocorrências que são iguais, é só moditficar o `.merge` para bater em ambas as colunas do DataFrame

```
new_df = df1.merge(df2, on=['id', 'valor'])
new_df.head()
#saida:

    id  valor
0   1   20
1   2   50
2   4   100
3   3   150
```

Se a ideia é preservar todas ocorrências da primeira planilha e verificar quais linhas são iguais a segunda, você pode fazer o `.merge` passando os parâmetros  **how = "LEFT"** e **indicator = True**

```
new_df = df1.merge(df2, on=['id', 'valor'], how = 'left', indicator = True)
new_df.head()
#saida
    id  valor   _merge
0   5   10      left_only
1   1   20      both
2   2   50      both
3   4   100     both
4   3   150     both
```

Mais informações sobre o comando `.merge` podem encontradas na [documentação](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)